# Making a PyTorch LSTM bidirectional=True causes: The size of tensor a (322) must match the size of tensor b (161) at non-singleton dimension 2

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, bidirectional

My model is:

```
class BaselineModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_dim=5, hidden_size=5, num_layers=2, seq_length=1, dropout=0.1):
        super(BaselineModel, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.seq_length = seq_length

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=feature_dim,
                            hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, dropout=0.1, bidirectional=False)

    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        return lstm_out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        hidden = torch.zeros(
            self.num_layers, self.seq_length, self.hidden_size)
        cell = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, self.seq_length,
                           self.hidden_size)
        return (hidden.float(), cell.float())
```

Everything works fine. My input and output have dimension `torch.Size([32, 15, 161])` and my `hidden` and `cell` have dimension `torch.Size([2, 15, 161])`.

But when I set `bidirectional=True`, the first thing I have to do is in my `init_hidden`, change `self.num_layers` to `self.num_layers * 2`. Which is fine. But then when I execute my training loop I get:

```
The size of tensor a (322) must match the size of tensor b (161) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

It's referring to the line that has `loss = loss_fn(pred, outputs)`. I'm using `loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')` if that matters. So what am I doing wrong?